# Can u answer about this time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm studying about time complexity analysis.

So I solve some exam about that.

Is there anyone who check my answer?
1.

```
x = 0;
for(i = 1; i<=N; i++)
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        for(k = 1; k <=j; k++)
            x += i + j + k;
```

I think that no.1 is O(n^3),,,, right?

2.

```
x = 0;
for(i = 1; i<=N; i++)
    for(j = 1; j <= i^i; j++)
        for(k = 1; k <=j; k++)
            x += i + j + k;
```

my answer is O(n^5)

```
3. 
x = 0;
for(i = 1; i<=N; i++)
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        if(j % i == 0)
            for(k = 1; k <=j; k++)
                x += i + j + k;
```

I really don't know what answer is ,,,,,

Help me~!

Comment: To understand the last one, remove the inner (`k`) loop, and replace it with a `printf` that prints `i` and `j`.

Comment: How can 2 be O(n^5)? If n=6, the second loop will execute `1^1+2^2+3^3+4^4+5^5+6^6` times. And the inner loop executes `j` times for every iteration of the second loop. That algorithm is at least `O(n^(n+1))`.

Comment: By `i ^ i` I assume you mean `pow(i, i)`? In the C-family of languages `^` is exclusive OR, and any value XOR'd with itself is zero.

Answer (score 0):

In the 3rd question, see the condition j%i == 0. This is true only when j=i,that is, the k loop will run only when i=j for every i from 1 to n. So, the complexity of the code is
O(n^2).